# How to post tweet from iPhone without PIN using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine?

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I am developing a iPhone application which sends tweets to twitter. For this I am using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine + MGTwitterEngine classes.

I register applicaiton to www.twitter.com/apps and pass Consumer key and Consumer secret to controller my code is this.

```
if(!_engine){
    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey    = slPcFUjUh5y1hex0zvEhPg;
    _engine.consumerSecret = u6ydovMdP9yeiVqDukVhIzZPgJR9XDPUwfxymzNs;  
}

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];

if (controller){
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    intTwitterFlag = 1;
}
```

Previously on twitter.com/apps I select Application type = client and my application will generate PIN and accessToken. But when i change my Application type = Browser it cannot generate PIN and accessToken.

Previously when application type is client i am giving user name and password and then control return to my application from the webview but now after entering user name and password it cannot dismissModalViewController but showing Select and Copy the PIN.

Thank you for your time and any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use xAuth route for mobile apps

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth

check XAuthTwitterEngine which implements xauth for the MGTwitterEngine

Comment: thanks for suggestion can u give me XAuthTwitterEngine example like SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.

Comment: https://github.com/aral/MGTwitterEngineDemo apparently xAuthTwitterEngine is deprecated because the MGTwitterEngine now supports xauth and oauth

Comment: just a note.. to use xauth you need to contact twitter and ask for xauth activation for your app

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:just replace the method in SA_OAuthTwitterController.m:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) webView {
    _loading = NO;
    //[self performInjection];
    if (_firstLoad) {
        [_webView performSelector: @selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject: @"window.scrollBy(0,200)" afterDelay: 0];
        _firstLoad = NO;
    } else {
        /*
        NSString                    *authPin = [self locateAuthPinInWebView: webView];
        NSLog(@"authPin: %@", authPin);
        if (authPin.length) {
            [self gotPin: authPin];
            return;
        }

        NSString                    *formCount = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.forms.length"];

        if ([formCount isEqualToString: @"0"]) {
            [self showPinCopyPrompt];
        }*/

        //*****************************************************
        //  This is to bypass the pin requirement 
        //  in case the call back URL is set in Twitter settings
        //*****************************************************     
        [_engine requestAccessToken];
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(OAuthTwitterController:authenticatedWithUsername:)])
        {
            [_delegate OAuthTwitterController: self authenticatedWithUsername: _engine.username];

        }
        [self performSelector: @selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) withObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue afterDelay: 1.0];

        //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    _blockerView.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if ([_webView isLoading]) {
        _webView.alpha = 0.0;
    } else {
        _webView.alpha = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue, and i just removed callback url from the twitter app settings. For my surprise login proceeds without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement for this method

```
(void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) webView
```

in the class `SA_OAuthTwitterController.m` works well.